# Client Side Pagination

Tags: javascript, search, pagination

What are the best libraries available right now for client side pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) is a good choice because you usually want a table with sorting when you're displaying data, and it also has pagination built in, so you get the whole shebang.

Comment: There's also BootGrid. http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/

Answer (score 1):

YUI also has a very easy to use [client-side pagination control](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_clientpagination.html).

Answer (score 0):

This one is fairly good too and works with HTML tables without expecting a table model. Comes with both pagination and sorting.

http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2007/10/19/client-side-table-pagination-script

Edit:
    Having now used the "[jquery tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)" script, I have to say it is better than the "client-side-table-pagination-script".